# No Naive Set Theoretic Models of Polymorphic Lambda Calculus?

Tags: functional-programming

In Philip Wadler's paper on [Theorems for Free](http://ttic.uchicago.edu/~dreyer/course/papers/wadler.pdf) he states in Section 2 on Parametricity that

> there are no naive set-theoretic models of polymorphic lambda calculus

In the naive set-theoretic model types are sets and functions are set-theoretic functions which seems reasonable. So why does he say there are no naive set-theoretic models of polymorphic lambda calculus?

Comment: OK, I just stumbled on this paper: https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00076261/document. I'm gonna have to plough through it.

Comment: That paper by Reynolds is indeed the right paper to read! Omitting _a lot_ of details it sums up to: consider `data T = K ((T -> Bool) -> Bool)`. Then, `T` and `((T->Bool)->Bool)` are isomorphic. If they have a set model where `->` denotes the function space (as a set), the latter has a higher cardinality, so it can't be isomorphic to `T`. So, in a model, we need to interpret `->` differently -- e.g. as the space of _continuous_ functions.

Comment: I answered too quickly and answered the wrong question.  Sorry about that. The reason for polymorphic lambda calculus not having a model in naive set theory is apparently rather different than the one for untyped lambda calculus.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The standard reference you are looking for is indeed Reynold's [*Polymorphism is not Set Theoretic*](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F3-540-13346-1_7). While it is quite obvious that you cannot form, e.g. the product $\Pi_{S\in\mathrm{Set}}S$ over all sets using the usual set theoretic product, it's a legitimate, and non-trivial question whether there is some weaker notion of product that would work, while preserving the usual binary product $\times$ and function space $\rightarrow$.

This turns out to not be possible either, since on one hand, it is rather easy to build a type $\bf 2$ such that the interpretation has at least 2 elements, and show that the interpretation of $T=\Pi_X(X\rightarrow {\bf 2})\rightarrow{\bf 2}$ is isomorphic to $(T\rightarrow {\bf 2})\rightarrow {\bf 2}$, which is not possible for the usual interpretation of $\rightarrow$ by the usual cantor paradox. In this sense it is somewhat similar to the proof for the untyped calculus.

Note that a further paper, by Andrew Pitts, [*Polymorphism is Set Theoretic, Constructively*](http://www.pps.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~mellies/mpri/mpri-ens/articles/pitts-polymorphism-is-set-theoretic-constructively.pdf), overturns this conclusion somewhat by showing that the above contradiction is only possible to construct in **classical** set theory, and that there are several constructive theories of sets in which polymorphism *can* be interpreted with the usual interpretations of functions spaces and products. Most notably these "large products" exists in the Effective Topos, the most comprehensive of introductions being given by [Phoa](http://www.lfcs.inf.ed.ac.uk/reports/92/ECS-LFCS-92-208/ECS-LFCS-92-208.ps.gz).